# Plus sign in a UL bullet list?

Tags: html

I need to have a bullet list to generate some tabs in a page.
This is the page I'm currently working on:

http://citydev.pipehosting.it/francia-en-it/parigi-it/torre-eiffel.html

I need to write "+Info" in one of the tabs - which are all `<li>` elements - but it's shown as "Info+" instead... (as seen when visiting the link).

My HTML for the list:

```
<ul class="tabs"> 
    <li class="current"><strong>Prodotto</strong></li> 
    <li>Cosa include</li>
    <li>In evidenza</li> 
    <li>Come funziona</li> 
    <li>Consegna</li>
    <li>+Info</li> 
    <li>Video</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: You should write here what you have tried so far. Regarding the question: Have you tried using CSS to display a '+' instead of a bullet?

Comment: @Abrixas2 The + should *only* appear in front of the `Info` list item, not in front of *every* list item.

Comment: @Dreamonic is correct. I don't want to use the plus sign as bullet, just the bulet to read "+Info"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the direction of the text in the tab list is set to `right to left`. To fix modify the css to override this declaration to `left to right`:

```
.tabs li {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

or remove `direction: rtl;` from where it is set on `ul.tabs`.

Comment: Thanks a million! This worked!
I don't know why it was set as RTL ??? Maybe my colleauge, which is of Russian origin grabbed some HTML code from some Russian forum/blog and this was set this way...

Comment: it was indeed on ul.tabs

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like this:

```
ul li:before { 
    content: "+"; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: -5px;
}
ul li { 
    text-indent: -5px; 
}
```

Check [list style types on W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/list-style-type) for more info.

**[Sample DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/trip007/3f2vb/3/)**

Comment: but i only need it on one of the bullet, this will add it before "any" bullet, I am afraid...

Comment: The + should *only* appear in front of the `Info` list item, not in front of *every* list item.

Comment: @R.T.: i don't need the "+" sign as bullet, I just need it on the "+Info" list item...